# Error occurring when using v-model in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, typescript-eslint

The following error produced by ESLint when using v-model in Quasar/Vue 3

Model of the component; Either use this property (along with a listener for 'update:modelValue' event) OR use v-model directive

```
<q-input class="q-pa-lg" outlined :dense='true' id="username" label="Email" type="text" v-model="v$.email.$model" :error="v$.email.$error" :error-message="v$?.email?.$errors[0]?.$message" autofocus/>
```

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Argument of type ‘unknown’ is not assignable to parameter of type string | number | null | undefined

This error is a general Typescript error, happening when type of input data/variable is `unknown`.

In your case, type of `v$.email.$model` is `unknown` and type of v-model will accept `string`.

I am not sure about the exact fix but you can have a look in this [Doc](https://dev.to/vcpablo/vuejs-2-different-ways-to-implement-v-model-1mjf) (VueJS - Different ways to implement v-model)